# Calculate the best lat and lng location for a GMaps map

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I have an array with 10 different latitude and longitude numbers gathered from GMaps. I want to show all of them on the same map in the same time. What I need to achieve, is calculate the best latitude and longitude values and zoom level (or have a formula that would calculate them for a certain zoom level), so that all markers are visible.

I am able to implement a math formula into a language of my choice, but any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to add them all to a LatLngBounds object and then use the .getCenter() function, with JavaScript. Here's a psuedo-code example for V2:

```
var bounds = new GLatLngBounds();

for(var i;i < array.length();i++)
{
    bounds.extend(new GLatLng(array[i].lat, array[i].lng));
}

bounds.getCenter();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not use V3 API. Is this possible in V2?

Comment: Yes...same thing (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GLatLngBounds). Just imagine a G in front of my object declarations.

Comment: side note, you may want to switch to the V3 API since V2 is deprecated and could be shut off as early as next year.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to calculate.

Create a new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); then add google.maps.LatLng to this bounds with the extends method.

Then you just have to use the setCenter() of the map with the bounds.getCenter()

You also can retrieve N/E and S/W lat and lng of your bounds.